# editing-help / links

Tags: feature-request, help-pages

The **editing-help** page does not mention the simplest types of links:

```
Here's a really simple link to [Google].

  [google]: http://www.google.com/
```

Are these types of links deliberately discouraged for some reason, or was it an oversight?

https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help:

> ### Basic Links
>
> There are three ways to write links.
>   Each is easier to read than the last:
>
> ```
> Here's an inline link to [Google](http://www.google.com/).
> Here's a reference-style link to [Google][1].
> Here's a very readable link to [Yahoo!][yahoo].
>
>   [1]: http://www.google.com/
>   [yahoo]: http://www.yahoo.com/
> ```
>
> The link definitions can appear
>   anywhere in the document -- before or
>   after the place where you use them.
>   The link definition names [1] and
>   [yahoo] can be any unique string, and
>   are case-insensitive; [yahoo] is the
>   same as [YAHOO].